# Two CABasicAnimations on Two Different Layers Simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I have a single animation that animates a layer mask successfully:

```
// create new animation
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
anim.delegate = self
anim.fromValue = self.maskLayerMWB.path
anim.toValue = path2.CGPath
anim.duration = 0.2
anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0, 1, 1, 1)
 self.maskLayerMWB.addAnimation(anim, forKey: nil)

CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
 self.maskLayerMWB.path = path2.CGPath
CATransaction.commit()
```

Above works fine.  However, right after that, I need to add another CABasicAnimation that gets applied to a different CAShapeLayer.

However, when I add them together as follows, the second animation does not animate, only the first does:

```
   // create new animation
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    anim.delegate = self
    anim.fromValue = self.maskLayer.path
    anim.toValue = path2.CGPath
    anim.duration = 0.2
     self.maskLayer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: nil)

   //Create second Animation
    let anim2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    anim2.delegate = self
    anim2.fromValue = self.shapeLayer.path
    anim2.toValue = path2.CGPath
    anim2.duration = 0.2
     self.shapeLayer.addAnimation(anim2, forKey: nil)

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
     self.maskLayer.path = path2.CGPath
     self.shapeLayer.path = path2.CGPath
    CATransaction.commit()
```

I need both animations to happen simultaneously.

Comment: What "does not work"?

Comment: Hello again.  Second animation does not animate, it just goes to the final value (shape).

Comment: Delete the begin and commit, and move the three lines they contained to the start.

Comment: Shouldn't he delete the `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
` as well?

Comment: No he should not.

Comment: That didn't work :( Now both wouldn't animate..just abruptly change to final value

Comment: What is this `path2` — is it a UIBezierPath? I'll make a demo...

Comment: Oh, I also need to know what Swift version this is.

Comment: Swift 2.3.  Also I am running this inside a timer with 1.0 sec interval.  May be sticking with just CATransaction is better?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by using **CATransaction.setCompletionBlock**

```
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

    // create new animation
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    anim.delegate = self
    anim.fromValue = self.maskLayer.path
    anim.toValue = path2.CGPath
    anim.duration = 0.2
     self.maskLayer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: nil)

   //Create second Animation
    let anim2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    anim2.delegate = self
    anim2.fromValue = self.shapeLayer.path
    anim2.toValue = path2.CGPath
    anim2.duration = 0.2
     self.shapeLayer.addAnimation(anim2, forKey: nil)

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
       self.maskLayer.path = path2.CGPath
       self.shapeLayer.path = path2.CGPath
    })

    CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Good enough for me! (Actually the same idea as what I was trying to do, but never mind why.)